# How to best fit a customview of Floating Action Button together with Listview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, floating-action-button

I have a XML layout with edittext listview and a fab included in a linearlayout which it takes a large part on screen and if I remove weight or play with it I get a very small button or cropped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:hint="Αναζητηση" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listCustomers"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cross" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How I can have a best fit of these three elements here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your complete layout with below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Αναζητηση"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listCustomers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_margin="9dp"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cross"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes looks nice but fab button covers text of and imagebutton of listview item

Comment: Just add android:layout_below="@+id/listCustomers" to FloatActionButton and it will not cover them.